# How to find the 4th and 5th coefficients (a_4 and a_5) of the serie expansion of cos(1-cos(x))

Tags: taylor-expansion

How to find the 4th and 5th coefficients
($a_4 $and $a_5$) of the serie expansion of cos(1-cos(x))

The 1 cancel with the 1 of the taylor serie of the 2nd cosine, now I have

cos( x^2/(2!)-x^4/(4!)+..).

What am I supposed to do next ? Take the taylor serie of this entire thing, that would be a mess, don’t you think ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which order are you interested in?

Comment: The order is not specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's exactly what you're supposed to do. Note, however, that you don't need any more than $\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}{24}$, as any higher order terms will clearly only contribute to $a_6$ and higher. As you're expanding $\cos\left(\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^4}{24}\right)$ you can also rememeber that you don't need the terms with higher degree than $5$, which means you can discard a lot of terms as you apply the binomial theorem.

It's less of a mess than you think, I think.

Comment: To add to @Arthur 's answer - you actually don't need to calculate $a_5$ since $\cos$ is an even function. (I assumed $a_5$ is the coefficient in front of $x^5$, not the $5$th coeficient in the expansion)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Does it mean that a_5 is just 0 ?

Comment: @Poujh Yes, by evenness of all the functions involved, any $a_n$ for odd $n$ is $0$. But in the course of calculating $a_4$, you could also just keep track of $a_5$ and see that it is $0$, at almost no additional calculation cost. There just isn't any $x^5$ anywhere.

Comment: Last question, I get 1/8 for a_4, which I got with (x^2/(2!)-x^4/(4!))^2 divided by 2! (the second term of the taylor serie of the first cosine), does that also seem correct to you ? (Just want to be sure )

Comment: @Poujh $\frac18$ is what i got too. All in all, $f(x) = 1-\frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{x^6}{24} + \cdots$.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot !